# Small angles between independent centred random walks in $ \mathbb{Z}^d$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks

Let $W_n$ and $W'_n$ denote two independent random walks in $ \mathbb{Z}^d$ defined using a finitely supported centred (mean zero) probability measure on $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

For $N \ge 1$, let
$\theta_n$ denote the smallest angles realized between $W_n$ and $W'_n$ during the period $ 1 \le n \le N$:

$$ \theta_N:= \min_{ 1 \le n \le N} \cos^{-1} \left|  \frac{ \langle W_n, W'_n \rangle }{ \| W_n \| \| W'_n\|}  \right|.$$

Are there any known results about how fast this quantity tends to zero? More precisely, I am looking for a statement of the form: with probability $1$, there are infinitely many $N \ge 1$ for which $\theta_N< f(N)$, where $f(N)$ is an explicit function tending to zero as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to study the angle of Wn and W'n separately with some axis because there have been studies on the angle of random walks on spheres eg. "Random Walk on Spheres " https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00536088.pdf.